# terraform; why is metadata referenced via a list indexing syntax?

Tags: terraform

Example: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/service_account.html

We see this:

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "terraform-example"
  }
  secret {
    name = "${kubernetes_secret.example.metadata.0.name}"
  }
}
```

Metadata is not a list, why does the secret/name value reference metadata using `.0`?

Comment: have you tested it with .0 and without .0 ? whats the outcome?

Comment: without 0 complains that metadata is a list, im asking for clarity around why that is, since it seems to be an object, and I cant think of an example where you need two or N metadata blocks in an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The provider has defined the `metadata` block type as being represented internally as a list of objects. This is common in today's Terraform providers because Terraform versions prior to Terraform v0.12 required a provider to choose between only lists and sets as the backing data type for nested block types.

Terraform v0.12 and later do support having a singleton block represented as a single object, but providers that predated the Terraform v0.12 release tend to still use the list representation for backward-compatibility. (Most providers are, at the time of writing, still compatible with both Terraform v0.11 and v0.12 in their new releases.)

[The *new* `kubernetes` provider](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/deploy-any-resource-with-the-new-kubernetes-provider-for-hashicorp-terraform/) (still under development at the time I'm writing this) was built specifically for Terraform v0.12 and later, so it is able to more directly reflect the underlying Kubernetes schema, including treating `metadata` as a single object. The announcement post about the new provider version includes this example:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "example_crd" {
  provider = kubernetes-alpha

  manifest = {
    apiVersion = "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1"
    kind = "CustomResourceDefinition"
    metadata = {
      name = "testcrds.hashicorp.com"
      labels = {
        app = "test"
      }
    }
    spec = {
      group = "hashicorp.com"
      names = {
        kind = "TestCrd"
        plural = "testcrds"
      }
      scope = "Namespaced"
      versions = [
        {
          name = "v1"
          served = true
          storage = true
          schema = {
            openAPIV3Schema = {
              type = "object"
              properties = {
                data = {
                  type = "string"
                }
                refs = {
                  type = "number"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The metadata name for this new provider can be accessed in a more intuitive way, because `metadata` is a single object:

```
kubernetes_manifest.example_crd.manifest.metadata.name
```

Comment: great explanation, I never would have found out this "historical" reasoning, much appreciated